# No splash screen, game not loading, just black screen?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Well i noticed a strange bug. I exported my app today and tested it on two phones.

My moto g4 plus ( android 7.0 ) worked fine and the app started with a splash screen, loaded and showed my ingame menu.

My honor 10 ( android 8.1 ) didnt worked fine... On app start the unity splash screen didnt showed up, just a black screen. Even after minutes nothinf happened, my ingame menu never showed up.

So basically i have no idea why this happens...

Did anyone had the same iusses and solved them ? Or does anyone know how to solve this or why this happens ?

Comment: You should post your code as part of the question.

Comment: @billy.mccarthy well... This is a general question... If you want i could post about 10k lines of rows but that wont help us either...

Comment: @generay can you post your Log?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @billy.mccarthy 2017.1.3f ... That should be fine ... Atleast i only found similar iusses on older versions.

Comment: Yeah i'm just trying to scour for a similar issue / known issue but can find much. Have you reported the issue to Unity?

Comment: Error Log? Debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to see logs on your phone.

Plug your phone to your PC, make sure ADB is on from developer options.

And then in CMD run this command:

```
adb logcat -s Unity PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG
```

I hope it helps you.